# Eclipse Debugger Already Running

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, terminate

I have recently started using Eclipse again after a couple year 'break'. I would like to use the built in debugger but when I click the debug button nothing seems to happen.. and even if I click the red Terminate button if I hover over the debugger button it says "(already running)"  From tutorials that I've watched, when the debugger button is click, Eclipse is supposed to open the Debug window (the button is located at the top right of eclipse) but even when I manually click that button it never shows me in the code where the debugger is currently executing.
Does anyone have any suggestions for getting my Eclipse debugger working??

Answer (score 1):

To my best knowledge, it seems your IDE Perspective Modes need to be switched. You should be able to see two tabs(Java and Debug bug symbol) on the right hand side (top) of the Eclipse IDE. If you switch perspective, you can see the debugger running. The IDE should actually ask you for the first time when you are running in Debug mode (using breakpoints) whether you would like to open this perspective as defualt everytime you hit debug mode. Try and see if this works. This is probably why you see that your debugging is already in action, but you never saw it taking place and hitting the breakpoints (i.e. it was invisible to you).

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment , it seems like you didn't terminate the eclipse debug mode .
If it is yes please follow the below procedure-

> open  the eclipse and write down the code.
>   put the debug the point and run as debug mode
>   and after the debug the code  terminate the debug mode using Ctrl+F2 or click on terminate.